# Use loop index number in a Twig variable

Tags: templating, variable, forloop, loop

Let's say I have 5 Craft fields named "item1" thru "item5."

Instead of writing out each variable...

```
{{ entry.item1 }}
{{ entry.item2 }}
{{ entry.item3 }}
{{ entry.item4 }}
{{ entry.item5 }}
```

How can I create a loop to do this for me?

I've tried this...

```
{% for i is 1..5 %}

    {{ entry.item ~ loop.index }}

{% endfor %}
```

But it returns the error:

> Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "item".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer in the Twig documentation:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables

> You can use a dot (.) to access attributes of a variable (methods or properties of a PHP object, or items of a PHP array), or the so-called "subscript" syntax ([]):

```
{{ foo.bar }}
{{ foo['bar'] }}
```

When using the subscript syntax, you can concatenate the loop.index like so:

```
{% for i is 1..5 %}

    {{ entry['item' ~ loop.index] }}

{% endfor %}
```

Or even simpler, use the `i` variable from the for loop.

```
{% for i is 1..5 %}

    {{ entry['item' ~ i] }}

{% endfor %}
```